# Animating a div's width with transform property

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want my div to show from left to right by altering it's width. But when `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` is present, the div's width animates from it's center to the assigned position.

I can't really change the `position` to anything but `absolute` since the div is placed in a specific spot.

```css
.Container{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 150px;
     
    animation: Animate 3s forwards;
}

.Container:after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 90%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
        transform: skew(-35deg);
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }

@keyframes Animate{
    from{
        width: 0px;
    }
    to{
        width: 250px;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="projDescription">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <br>
    <a href="#">Help?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would it be better if I used Jquery instead?

Also, I'll ask this here too since it has to do with the same div; can I animate the `:after` pseudo element? It's mostly just there to give the div an angled style, and I know I could've just used something else to style it. But I was just curious if it is possible.

Comment: second question: yes, you can animate :after, atleast with transition properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `transform` property from your `.Container` class and use `calc()` if you know the exact value of the `width` and `height`

```css
.Container{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 75px);
    left: calc(50% - 125px);
    height: 150px;
    animation: Animate 3s forwards;
}


.Container:after{
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 90%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
        transform: skew(-35deg);
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }

@keyframes Animate{
    from{
        width: 0px;
    }
    to{
        width: 250px;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd move some attributes to inner classes and made small modifications to achieve it; and also I used `scale` for width expansion animation instead of animation `width` property, to avoid an unnecessary [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow)

```css
.Container{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}

.projDescription{
    height: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100% ;
    animation: Animate 3s forwards;
}

.Container:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 90%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
    transform: skew(-35deg) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    z-index: 99;
    animation: move 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes Animate{
    to{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@keyframes move{
    to{
        transform: skew(-35deg) translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="projDescription">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
    <p>Hello</p>

    <a href="#">Help?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```